# What module should I use to save a module settings in a feature?

Tags: 7, features, strongarm

I am needing some additional power for my Features.  I have several modules that have their own settings (like css injector... yeah, I know) which do not appear in teh list of items that can be saved within a feature.  I have been told that [Strongarm](https://drupal.org/project/strongarm) offers a good way to include additional configuration within a feature (above and beyond what Features can normally store.)  I have also heard talk of another module that is (commonly?) used with Features which improves its ability to store and transfer configurations.  I can not remember the name of this other module.  Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many modules store their settings in variables, that's what Strongarm is good for : it can help you export those variables with features.

My usual way of finding out which variable to export (and exporting it) :

- see the source HTML of the form where you set the values
- in the "name" attribute you will most often find the name of the variable
- use [drush vget](http://www.drushcommands.com/drush-6x/variable/variable-get) *that_variable* to check if it exists

  - `drush vget` is useful because it searches all variables that have a name similar to the string you provide, so sometimes you can do some testing to see other variables that could be useful
- if you confirm the name of the variable, put it into the feature's info file

  - `features[variable][] = that_variable`
- run [drush fu](http://www.drushcommands.com/drush-6x/features/features-update) your_feature

  - this will export the variable's value

The other module you heard off might have been [Features Extra](https://drupal.org/project/features_extra). Me personally i don't find it that useful anymore.

There is a [free video](http://drupalize.me/videos/introduction-drupal-features-module) on drupalize.me about features. And [an article](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/features) on d.o.